# Week 4 CS50 Filter: Getting black image as output for blur function

Tags: c, cs50

So I used the following code for the blur function:

```
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    // Setting counter as 1 as the initial element is also being included when taking the average
    float counter = 1.00;

    // Creating a temporary array so as to avoid the effect of blurring one pixel from affecting the other pixels
    RGBTRIPLE temporary[height][width];


    // Making both arrays the same
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width ; j++)
            {
                temporary[i][j] = image[i][j];
            }
        }

    // Looping through each pixel i.e. image[i][j]
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width ; j++)
            {
                int total_red = temporary[i][j].rgbtRed;
                int total_green = temporary[i][j].rgbtGreen;
                int total_blue = temporary[i][j].rgbtBlue;

                // Looping through each surrounding pixel with respect to image[i][j]
                for (int x = -1; x < 2; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = -1; y < 2; y++)
                    {
                        int currentX = i + x;
                        int currentY = j + y;

                        // Condition for when a pixel is invalid
                        if ((currentX < 0) || (currentY < 0) || (currentX > (height - 1)) || (currentY > (width - 1)))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                      // Add the valid pixel's RGB values to the total and increment the counter
                        total_red += temporary[currentX][currentY].rgbtRed;
                        total_green += temporary[currentX][currentY].rgbtGreen;
                        total_blue += temporary[currentX][currentY].rgbtBlue;

                        counter++;
                    }

                }

                // Take average and round
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(total_red / counter);
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(total_green / counter);
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(total_blue / counter);

            }
        }

    return;
}
```

But this code gives a black image as output. I tried with counter = 0 and setting the values for total_red, total_green and total_blue equal to 0...but that made no difference either. Can someone help me out with what might be wrong with my code?

image[height][width] is an array of rgb structures. Each structure has 3 attributes, rgbtRed, rgbtGreen, and rgbtBlue.

Here's a link to the problem: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/psets/4/filter/less/

Comment: `counter` isn't reset on each iteration of the loop. It should be inside the loop like the sum variables. You're also adding the center point twice since you initialize the sum variables with `temporary[i][j].xxx`.